# Preserving index order of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

After much filtering and cleaning up of my input unstructured data, I have now constructed the RDDs of Strings RDD[(String) where the various parms are comma separated for further use. One of the prerequisites is that I need to index groups of string such as the following

```
val inputRDD1:RDD[(String,Long)] = myUtilities.paragraphFile(spark,path1)
                                         .coalesce(100*spark.defaultParallelism) 
                                          .zipWithIndex() //RDD[String, Long]
                                          .filter(f => f._2!=0)

 val cleanedRDD1 = myUtilities.cleanSplitData(inputRDD1)
                                .saveAsTextFile("/home/path/cleanedrdd1")

1,parm1,parm2,parm3..
1,parm1,parm2,parm3..
1,parm1,parm2,parm3..
2,parm1,parm2,parm3..
2,parm1,parm2,parm3..
3,parm1,parm2,parm3..
3,parm1,parm2,parm3..
3,parm1,parm2,parm3..
3,parm1,parm2,parm3..
.
.
```

The above output format is required to run group operations based on the index. This works well when the input file is small. However when the file size is large, the index starts at 1 again based on the number of partitions. 
I was able to test this by saving the intermediate rdd

The cleanedrdd1 dir has several part files (when the input file is large) and each part file begins the index at 1. Instead I need the part files to be continuous. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT1:

```
def cleanSplitData(inputRDD:RDD[(String)]): org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = {
      var cntflag = false
      val cleanedRDD = inputRDD
                              .flatMap(line  => line._1.split("\n")) //split at newline
                              //Note: a bunch of filtering operations are run prior to this step.
                              .map(row => {
                                //This step is to make sure rows following a row starting with "D," or "#" have the same index. 
                                //This is required to run groupBy/AggBy operations later. Hence the counter cnt.
                                if(row.startsWith("D,") || row.startsWith("#")){ cntflag=true } else cntflag=false 
                                if(cntflag==true)  cnt+=1
                                (cnt + "," + row)
                              })            
      return cleanedRDD
      }
```

Comment: I can't replicate this.  `rdd.zipWithIndex()` provides the absolute index, not the index in each partition.  Please post the contents of your utility functions.

Comment: @TimP - Added the definition for the utility func cleanSplitData.